# Counting total and unique clicks on a link using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php

I want to show following stats for a link which is generated from mysql database:

1) Total Clicks

2) Total Unique Clicks

3) Today Clicks

4) Today Unique Clicks

So far, I have just managed to count total clicks. There are many links in table and I am showing them randomly and I am making the user jump to another page from index.php to redirect.php 
...

I am using this code on links...

```
//displaying links
<a target="_blank" href="redirect.php?id=<?php echo $url_id ; ?>">
```

On redirect.php I am using this code in order to increase clicks and then lastly, redirecting to the url...

```
<?php

    //catching id of url using get method
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    //query to increment clicks
    $query = "UPDATE tablename SET clicks_count = clicks_count + 1 WHERE url_id = $id";

    $increment_clicks_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    //query to fetch url
    $query = "SELECT url FROM tablename WHERE url_id = $id"; 

    $redirect_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($redirect_query)){

        $url = $row['url'];

    }

    //now redirecting to the url 
    echo("<script>location.href='$url';</script>");

?>
```

Comment: How do you identify the click as unique click?

Comment: I don't know :-(...

Comment: Well, you have to think about a concept how to identify a click as unique click, otherwise you cannot count them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store each click with a timestamp so you can sort them into days later for the report.

For unique clicks, assign each user a session variable and/or a cookie once they click the link and make your code check for the cookie/session variable and record "0" in a "unique" column if they have the variable or cookie ("1" if they don't).

Session variable would be "unique for each session" or a cookie that lasts a long time would do a better job of eliminating "unique" clicks for multiple visits/sessions to the site from the same user. But they could always clear their cookies or use a different browser I guess.

This logic would be if you have one unique and one non-unique row. You could also do one row with date as index, one col for unique clicks and one col for non-unique clicks I guess, but that would be very similar to this:

```
{Query to check if today's unique and non-unique rows exist in db}

if (today's rows don't exist) {
  {create unique clicks row in DB}
  {create non-unique clicks row in DB}
} 

if (user DOES have cookie or session var) {
  {increment non-unique clicks}
} else {
  {increment unique clicks}
  {set session variable or cookie}
}
```

Comment: Otherwise you can make a new column for each day based on the time and have 1 column for unique clicks and one for non-unique clicks, which are incremented. On each click do a query to check if that day's new column exists and if it doesn't, create the two rows (unique and non-unique).